# Can we consider Elasticsearch as state maintaining data-store for spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, hdfs

I know HDFS or S3 is the most preferred way of doing the checkpoint and state maintenance while working with Spark Streaming (D-Stream) but unable to find solid reasonings to deny ES for the same. In my case, the state is not going to be very heavy and neither it is going to be very frequent on using.

Comment: ES seems, to me, like a rather peculiar store for state. You use ES when you want to search text. Spark Streaming basically requires blob storage, which is kind of orthogonal to what we need here.

Comment: @Pranjut Have you actually used ES for that? If so, how?

Comment: No @ErnestKiwele . I am just trying to find out options. Do you think we cannot use ES for it? I am not sure if there any connector available but I think we can implement one and can use it.

Comment: @Pranjut I'd be surprised if we could. Checkpointing setup requires a FS directory, which I can't even see as an applicable concept for ES. Check this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#how-to-configure-checkpointing

Comment: Ah! Thank you @ErnestKiwele I got what I wanted.